# Let the user specify in which account a service runs

Tags: wix

I've got a windows service that should run under a domain account *specified by the user during installation*.

How is this possible with a `Wix` installer (i.e. ask the user for a account + password that the service should be using)?

**Background**

My service needs access to a network share and `LocalSystem` doesn't have the appropriate rights so I want to use an existing domain user account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ServiceInstall](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm) element is your friend here. It contains the attributes Account and Password.
So, author a couple of controls on your dialog:

```
<Control Type="Edit" Property="ACCOUNT" ... />
<Control Type="Edit" Property="PASSWORD" Password="Yes" ... />
```

And use these properties to instruct ServiceInstall:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="..." Account="[ACCOUNT]" Password="[PASSWORD]" Type="ownProcess" ... />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: I have to add my own custom dialog to the installer which asks the user for a account + password. I can use those values in the `ServiceInstall` element to set up an account. Correct? There is no standard, ready-made dialog I can use?

Comment: Correct. No, there's no standard dialog, as far as I know, but it should be quite simple to create it

Comment: Be careful when you set a password for the account. You have to acquire the information on uninstallation, too. See this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
'[...] after deleting a service that was installed with a user name and password, the installer cannot rollback the service without first using a custom action to get the password [...] The CA acquires the password by prompting the user, reading a property from the database, or reading a file. The custom action must then call ChangeServiceConfig, to supply the password, before reinstalling the service.'